# Functions value is not defined in PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html

I create this div in PHP and I want to call a function when I double=click on it. However, it tells me that my value isn't defined. Can someone please tell me why?

(Here's the important part of my code in php:

```
"..//Some mor HTML...value='".$DatabaseID.";' ondblclick='delete_selected(value, 'all', 'child'); ..//Some more HTML.."
```

I can call a function that doesn't have a value. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the rest if you're interested:

```
$Object = "<div id='".$DatabaseID."' onclick='sendid(id); highlight(id);' title='".$title."' data-parent='".$ParentID."'data-itemCategory='".$ItemCategory."' value='".$DatabaseID.";' ondblclick='delete_selected(value);' onmouseup='position(id);' style='border:".$border_size."px solid ".$border_color."; top:".$pos_y."px; left:".$pos_x."px; position:".$positionType."; background:".$color.";' class='".$class."'>
    <!-- <img src='$img' class='img_status_rwp' style='width:".$img_size."px; height:".$img_size."px; margin-left:-".$img_size."px; margin-top:-".$img_size."px; '></img> --> <div class='item_header'><div class='header_text_cont'><div class='header_span'>".$ItemName."</div><div style='clear:both';></div></div></div>";
```

### Update

I changed the quotation and removed te img-part (since it isn't active):

```
        $Object = '<div id="'.$DatabaseID.'" onclick="sendid('.$DatabaseID.'); highlight('.$DatabaseID.')"; title="'.$title.'" data-parent="'.$ParentID.'" data-itemCategory="'.$ItemCategory.'" value="'.$DatabaseID.'" onclick="show_children(value, "all", "child");" style="border:'.$border_size.'px solid '.$border_color.'; top:'.$pos_y.'px; left:'.$pos_x.'px; position:'.$positionType.'; background:'.$color.';" class="'.$class.'">
         <div class="item_header"><div class="header_text_cont"><div class="header_span">'.$ItemName.'</div><div style="clear:both";></div></div></div>';
```

I belive that the quotationmarks around all and child might be the ones creating some trouble but I don't know what to use instead.

show_children is defined in a JavaScript file that is included to the index.php and I can call other functions in it from index. I don't get any errors when double clicking, however the function is not called. When I successfully call the function using a button I have the following HTML:

```
            <div class="sidebar_button" id="childAll" value="" onclick="show_children(value, 'all', 'child'); " style="font-size:10px">Show All Child Nodes (To RWP)</div>
```

Comment: For starters, that quoting error is probably going to confuse a parser somewhere.  You're invoking `delete_selected()` within single-quotes *and* trying to pass single-quoted values to it.  Aside from that, well, did you define `delete_selected` anywhere?  Or `value`?  Or whatever the parser is claiming isn't defined?

Comment: Please include your actual code and the actual error message.

Comment: @David  How should I use the quotes? I belive everything is defined.

Comment: @e.klara.k: Believing things are defined isn't the same as defining them.  Parsers and compilers aren't interested in your beliefs.  As for the quotes, the HTML element attribute values should be in double-quotes.  For example: `ondblclick="delete_selected(value, 'all', 'child')"`  In order to use those double-quotes in your PHP string, you'll need to escape them or use some other PHP string notation.

Comment: @e.klara.k: You're also going to want to actually *debug* this.  Determine where the error is coming from.  PHP?  JavaScript?  Somewhere else?  If it's a JavaScript error, then examine your *client-side* code, not the *server-side* code which emits it.  Usually these problems are obvious if you look at the code.

Comment: @David Updated the question

Comment: @e.klara.k: You still have the *exact same* quoting problem.  For example: `onclick="show_children(value, "all", "child");"`  You can't directly use quotes inside of a quoted string like that.  The parser would have no way of knowing where one ends and the other begins.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies here `onclick='sendid(id); highlight(id);'` your passing `id` which isn't defigned anywhere. You need to change the code to `onclick='sendid(".$DatabaseID."); highlight(".$DatabaseID.");'` and then it should work.